# How to forward a Kerberos ticket over SSH using Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, kerberos, paramiko

I'm trying to forward a Kerberos ticket over SSH connection to keep using an authenticated session in Hive/Beeline.

I already do this by PuTTy, but I couldn't with Paramiko.

Someone knows if is possible to forward a Kerberos ticket over SSH using Paramiko? And how can I do that?

PS: Windows 10 client connected to a Linux Server.